# using div as a popup and refreshing the page behind

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to make a system where I am using div as a popup and entering values from div into database using PHP, the main concern is refreshing the page without closing the div(working as popup), reason behind this is that I am showing the content that is going into Database at real time.

I tried to open the div(pop up) again while refreshing the parent page using flag variable but it doesn't work, after page is refreshed I have to click on that button again that opens that div(pop up).

I don't want to open that div(popup) when the page is opened for the very first time.

This is the code to open the div(popup)

```
    function addteamappear()
    {   
        $("#illusion").show('slow');
        $("#addplayer").show('slow');


         var config = {
  '.chosen-select'           : {},
  '.chosen-select-deselect'  : {allow_single_deselect:true},
  '.chosen-select-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:10},
  '.chosen-select-no-results': {no_results_text:'Oops, nothing found!'},
  '.chosen-select-width'     : {width:"95%"}
}

function addteamclose()
    {   
        $("#illusion").hide('slow');
        $("#addplayer").hide('slow');
    }
```

This is the code I am using inside the div(popup) to enter into database, I have called the addteappear at the end of the function

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['tournamentteamssubmit']))
{
$addtournamentteams=$_POST['addtournamentteams'];
$query=mysql_query("select * from tournamentteams where team='".$addtournamentteams."' ");
if(mysql_num_rows($query)!=0)
{ 
    die ( "<script>alert('You have alredy added this team');</script>");

    }

$query=mysql_query("select * from teams where teamname='".$addtournamentteams."' ");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($query);

mysql_query("insert into tournamentteams( tournament,team,player1,player2) values(UPPER('".$tournamentname."'),UPPER('".$addtournamentteams."'),UPPER('".$row['player1']."'),UPPER('".$row['player2']."')) ") or die("ERROR :".mysql_error());
echo "<script>alert('Team Added Sucessfully');</script>";
   echo "<script>addteamclose(); addteamappear();</script>";
}
?>
```

I have tried my best to make my situation understood.

Comment: You could either put the content in the backround in an iframe or update it dynamically with Ajax.

Comment: I can't do this as the content there is editable and it has some effect on the current page

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand you. Why can't you use AJAX? Take look at http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: What effect does the editable content have?

Comment: deleting the rows from there and updating the information

Comment: @ncq http://bit.ly/KQcoyZ

Comment: If you're not using AJAX, how are you calling the php?  Is it the forms action?

Comment: the page has been saved as .php, where the code is required I have added the code there